# How to echo a database field after login?

Tags: php

I've coded a login, but I need to know, as a success message it echo's the user's first name. 

The first name is stored in the database in the same entry as the email.

I need to make an array, but I don't know how.

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($_POST['email']) {
        if ($_POST['password']) {

            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");

            if (mysql_fetch_array($p) != 0){

                echo "WHAT GOES HERE?";
                $registered = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email'"); 
                setcookie("PeopleHubLogged", ".$email.");

            } else {
             echo "<font color='red'>Login Failed</font>"; 
            }
        } else { 
        echo "<font color='red'>You need to enter a password!</font>";
        }
    } else { 
    echo "<font color='red'>You need to enter a email!</font>"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a couple suggestions. 1) this is injection prone. and should not face the internet, it is very easy to break. 2) use isset checks on post and get, otherwise your log will turn into an unreadable mess (if it isn't already). what do you mean by you need to make an array but you don't know how?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: How do I make the success message say "Hello, then the users first name."? The users firstname is stored in the database as FirstName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your table looks like, but is this what you are looking for?

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($_POST['email']) {
        if ($_POST['password']) {

            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");

            if (mysql_fetch_array($p) != 0){

                echo "WHAT GOES HERE?";
                $registered = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email'"); 
                setcookie("PeopleHubLogged", ".$email.");

                $outArr = mysql_fetch_array($registered);
                echo "Hello " . $outArr["FirstName"];

            } else {
             echo "<font color='red'>Login Failed</font>"; 
            }
        } else { 
        echo "<font color='red'>You need to enter a password!</font>";
        }
    } else { 
    echo "<font color='red'>You need to enter a email!</font>"; 
    }
}
```

I highly recommend you restructure this, eliminate the nesting, and use a different SQL driver. (look up PDO). Your code is dangerous. SQL injection could be applied to this code very easily, so I hope this never faces the internet. If you use the PDO driver properly, it will make SQL injection near impossible - therefore I highly recommend it.

Here is how I would write your code otherwise:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     echo "<font color='red'>You need to enter a email!</font>"; 
     return;
}
if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "<font color='red'>You need to enter a password!</font>";
    return;
}
if (!isset($_POST['password'])) {
    echo "<font color='red'>Login Failed</font>"; 
    return;
}

$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'");

if (mysql_fetch_array($p) != 0){

    echo "WHAT GOES HERE?";
    $registered = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$email'"); 
    setcookie("PeopleHubLogged", ".$email.");

    $outArr = mysql_fetch_array($registered);
    echo "name: " . $outArr["FirstName"];
}
```